# Проблема с nginx+php-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Начал разбираться с nginx'ом и столкнулся с такой проблемой: вместо обработки файла php, сервер отдает chrome сам файл, причем в ff работает все отлично. И при обращении к /index.php сервер отдает html, а не файл.
Проблема только с chrome.

Конфиг хоста:

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name phpmyadmin.local;
root /var/www/phpmyadmin.local;
index index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params; 
  }  
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: вероятно, какой-то из браузеров черпает информацию из собственного кэша.

Comment: Оформи ответом.